# ReactJS MUI Box how to create a smooth css transition after onclick

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, css-transitions

I have this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-pond-lx6hxz?file=/demo.tsx). This is a switch component approach based on divs, but I would like to add a smooth transition for the states, such as in this example https://codepen.io/nikkk-me/pen/abvPjeG. I added:

```
after: {
    transform: 'translateX(120px)',
    transition: 'transform 300ms linear'
  }
```

in the styled div, but it doesn't work. Any hint on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the syntax error in the added code, it seems that you would like to create this effect by animating a pseudo-element.

This can be done but will require writing a complete custom component, which kinda contradicts the purpose of using MUI.

But anyways, here is a quick draft example:

Live demo: [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-varahamihira-1peb6c?file=/demo.tsx)

```
// demo.tsx

import * as React from "react";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { Box, Typography } from "@mui/material";

const Selector = styled(Box)(({ selected }) => ({
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "center",
  cursor: "pointer",
  color: selected ? "white" : "inherit",
  borderRadius: selected ? "21px" : "unset",
  padding: "3px 20px 3px 20px",
  width: "50px",
  zIndex: "100",
  transition: "color 0.2s linear"
}));

export default function BoxSx() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState("first");

  function handleSelected() {
    setSelected(selected === "first" ? "second" : "first");
  }

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        display: "flex",
        background: "grey",
        width: "fit-content",
        borderRadius: "25px",
        p: "2px",
        isolation: "isolate",
        position: "relative",
        "&::before": {
          content: "''",
          position: "absolute",
          backgroundColor: "pink",
          padding: "3px 20px 3px 20px",
          width: "50px",
          borderRadius: "21px",
          zIndex: "50",
          top: "0",
          left: selected === "first" ? "0" : "93px",
          bottom: "0",
          transition: "left 0.2s linear"
        }
      }}
      onClick={handleSelected}
    >
      <Selector selected={selected === "first"} color="green">
        <Typography sx={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>First</Typography>
      </Selector>
      <Selector selected={selected === "second"} color="green">
        <Typography sx={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>Second</Typography>
      </Selector>
    </Box>
  );
}
```